# Calling javascript function using dot operator

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

```
function getPercCalculated(x){
  return (x*9.3)/100;
}

var x = 10;
var perx = getPercCalculated(x);
```

Instead of this I would like to call the getPercCalculated using dot operator like

```
var perx = x.getPercCalculated()
```

Can someone help me..!!

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: It is possible, but remember **it is a very bad practice** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: To do this you need to extend the [**Number.prototype**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/prototype) with this method, which is not very recommended as it will affect all created numbers.

You will need to use:

    `Number.prototype.getPercCalculated =  function (){
      return (this*9.3)/100;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Number.prototype.getPercCalculated= function(){
    return (this*9.3)/100;
};
```

This will attach the `getPercCalculated` to every number in your code tough

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked :)